# Filter Table Visual Using Or Logic Instead of Default And Logic

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Suppose I have a table, Sample_Table, of Names and IDs:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | 1 |
| Bob | 2 |
| Carl | 3 |

I want to create a user experience such that the user clicks a slicer for both Name and ID (edit interactions off), and all rows which match either slicer get returned.

For instance, if the user chooses "Anna" and "2", the output should then be:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | 1 |
| Bob | 2 |

Because Anna matched by name and Bob matched by ID.

I tried accomplishing this with the following DAX via a calculatetable:

```
selected_rows = 
var selected_name = "Anna" --SELECTEDVALUE(Sample_Names[Name])
var selected_ID = "2" --SELECTEDVALUE(Sample_IDs[ID])
return
CALCULATETABLE(
    Sample_Table,
    Sample_Table[Name] = selected_name || Sample_Table[ID] = selected_ID
    )
```

When I hardcode it like this, it works as expected, and the correct output appears. However, when I try to modify the code to attempt to use selectedvalue() as shown in the comments after "Anna" and "2" it breaks and no records are returned. I have included a slicer for Name and a slicer for ID on the canvas, and selected only "Anna" and "2" in these slicers.

The code that is creating the sample_names and sample_ids table are:

```
Sample_Names=VALUES(SampleTable[Name])
Sample_IDs=VALUES(SampleTable[ID])
```

I tried adding two separate tables disconnected from the Sample_Table as well for these slicers, since I thought possibly the fact they were both filtering the same table could be the issue.

I was expecting that using the selectedvalue() function and a slicer that it would pull the value from the slicer into the calculatetable() and therefore fulfill my needs, but it seems to just return nothing instead when I do that.

This leads me to believe that there might be some other way to accomplish the task or implement selectedvalue() to make it work.

I tried reviewing some other questions such as

[Using DAX in PowerBI, how can I build a dynamic table that lists the values selected in a two slicers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75597440/using-dax-in-powerbi-how-can-i-build-a-dynamic-table-that-lists-the-values-sele)

but this seems to be a slightly different use case and I did not see a clear path to adapting to my use case from the answer and discussion provided there.

Comment: The result of a slicer won't affect a Calculated Table, only a measure. Suggest you use a measure within the filters pane, applied to a table visual on the canvas, which is straightforward. Also, your use of `SELECTEDVALUE` suggests that the user is to be prohibited from making multi-selections within the slicers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps.

[image]

Tables like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Add the fact columns to the table visual and the dim columns to each of the slicers.

Create a measure:

```
Measure = 

VAR a = IF( ISFILTERED('IDs Dim'[ID]) && SELECTEDVALUE('Fact'[ID]) IN VALUES('IDs Dim'[ID]) ,1)
VAR b =  IF (ISFILTERED('Names Dim'[Name]) &&  SELECTEDVALUE('Fact'[Name]) IN VALUES('Names Dim'[Name]),1)

RETURN a+b
```

Add the measure to the visual filter of the table visual like this:

[image]